# How to filter results and manytomany childs?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am making a web page that display a "Kanban".
I have columns as well as cards.

I want to filter the results according to a field (priority) in the cards (Sale).

My models:

```py
class PipelineColumn(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=80)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Order of column"), unique=True)
    default_probability = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("probability"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("PipelineColumn")
        verbose_name_plural = _("PipelineColumns")
        ordering = ["order"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Sale(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=255)
    expected_income = models.FloatField(_("expected income"))
    probability = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("probability"))
    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        "crm.Person",
        verbose_name=_("person"),
        related_name="sale_person",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    date = models.DateField(_("date"), auto_now_add=True)
    scheduled_closing_date = models.DateField(_("scheduled closing date"))
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("priority"), default=0)
    column = models.ForeignKey(
        "crm.PipelineColumn",
        verbose_name=_("column"),
        related_name="sale_column",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Sale")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Sales")
        ordering = ["scheduled_closing_date", "-priority"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

For example, I would like to display only the columns and cards that have a priority of 2. If I try with `PipelineColumn.objects.filter(sale_column__priority=2)` it filters the columns well, only the columns with a sale with a priority equal to 2 are displayed. On the other hand, in the displayed columns all the sales are displayed even those whose priority is not equal to 2.

I would also like to be able to filter the sales returned by my query and get only the one whose priority is equal to 2.

For the moment I use the django-url-filter module to do this filtering.
My viewset:

```py
class PipelineColumnViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving PipelineColumn.
    """

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = PipelineColumnSerializer
    filter_backends = [
        DjangoFilterBackend,
        filters.SearchFilter,
        filters.OrderingFilter,
    ]
    search_fields = [
        "sale_column__name",
        "sale_column__contact__last_name",
        "sale_column__contact__first_name",
    ]
    filter_fields = ["is_done", "sale_column"]
    ordering = ["order"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        total = PipelineColumn.objects.aggregate(
            total=Sum("sale_column__expected_income")
        )["total"]
        return (
            PipelineColumn.objects.all()
            .annotate(total_ca=Sum("sale_column__expected_income"))
            .annotate(percentage_ca=(Sum("sale_column__expected_income") * 100 / total))
            .prefetch_related("sale_column")
        )
```

How to filter the sales in addition to the columns?

Comment: How about replacing `PipelineColumn.objects.all()` with `PipelineColumn.objects.filter(sale_column__priority=2).annotate(total_ca=Sum("sale_column__expected_income")).annotate(percentage_ca=(Sum("sale_column__expected_income") * 100 / total)).prefetch_related("sale_column")` in your `get_queryset` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you don't understand the problem. 
When I replace `PipelineColumn.objects.all()` with 
`PipelineColumn.objects.filter(sale_column__priority=2)` it filters the columns and not the sales.